# How to redirect the login to an app, model specific

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need that when I log in, it shows me directly an admin model..
Example, I have the app nameapp, and within the models nodel_one, model_two that are different tables, I need it to show me the records of one of those tables when entering after login.
How do I set the urls?

I have:

```py
# file: intrados/intrados/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('daytona/', include("daytona.urls")),
     path('', admin.site.urls), # home also goes to admin
]
```

And I need to go to

```py
# file: intrados/daytona/admin.py is in URL http://localhost:8000/admin/daytona/domain/

class DomainAdmin(SetReadOnlyModel, admin.ModelAdmin):
#xxxxxxxxx
```

te redirect specific table to see records